# 3G router for outdoor usage

Tags: wireless-networking, 3g, antenna

My boss have asked me to help find a solution for networking in our warehouses.
Since they are at a remote location, I need to find a solution that include a 3G router.
The warehouses are not heated.

I think the easiest way is to find an outdoor 3G router which supports [this](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-ANT2415D).

Can anyone help me?

Ps: I have looked at [this](http://www.lancom-systems.de/en/products/wireless-lan/outdoor-access-points/lancom-oap-3g/) but doesn't know if the antenna is supported.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. This is a shopping question, and its not something considered to be a good fit for the q&a format - [see this blog.se post for more details](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) Root access, our chat room is the preferred place for purchase recommendations, and you can access this if you had 20 reputation on any site on SE

Answer (score 1):

Unless your business is requiring a high-bandwidth connection, or many connected devices, you could devote a jailbroken iPhone with PDAnet installed.

I'm guessing that you probably can not use this method, or you won't jailbreak an iPhone, so... in that case, [here is an outdoor 3G router](http://www.maxxwave.com/docs/3g%20broadband%20router.pdf) that you may not have seen yet.

Comment: I would say that using a jailbroken iPhone / PDAnet for this would be a very strange choice because: A) you can buy 3G routers in the shops for less than the price of a second hand one B) it is not weatherproof C) You can't plug in an external aerial.

Comment: I understand, that is why I added the other router in my answer. BTW, you can put the iPhone in a weatherproof container. If his need for a 3G router was just a temporary requirement (or he doesn't care about using conventional utilities such as an iPhone), he could definitely do this.

Comment: As a comment on this answer, note that you don't need to jailbreak an Android to get tethering. Some carriers try to lock it down, but there are apps that don't require root (for Android versions less than 4.2.1) that can do both wired and wireless tethering. Wired tethering is still possible without root on even the latest build of Android no matter how locked down it is.

Comment: Yes. I guess that you can do this on Android as well, but, I don't have an Android so I am informing him of my method for doing this with an iPhone.